# Why does this query not return records where both fields using CASE WHEN are zero?

Tags: mysql, query, sum

I'm attempting challenge 13 on [this](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation) SQLzoo page, but my query returns one fewer row than it's supposed to.

```
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score1,
  team2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score2
  FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

When both SUM values would be zero, the query just doesn't return than record and I've no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) on `goal` to pick up the 0-0 games.

```
SELECT mdate, 
  team1,
  sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
team2, 
  sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
  FROM game 
LEFT OUTER JOIN goal ON matchid = id
group by mdate, matchid, team1,team2
order by mdate, matchid, team1 ,team2
```

You were nearly there.